# MariaDB move database to user home

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, mysql, acl

I'm trying to move some databases to the home directory of a user but facing issues on a Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
Here's what I've done:
Created a new database for this setup. Named it "test"

1. Create 'databases' directory in /home/admin/
2. Change ownership of /home/admin/databases to mysql:mysql
3. Move database directory `mv /var/lib/mysql/test /home/admin/databases/test`
4. Create symlink `sudo -u mysql ln -s /home/admin/databases/test /var/lib/mysql/test`
5. Restart mariadb service

Now in syslog I'm getting these errors

```
[ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 13 in a file operation.
[ERROR] InnoDB: The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to the directory.
[ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot open datafile for read-only: './test/test.ibd' OS error: 81
[ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 13 in a file operation.
[ERROR] InnoDB: The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to the directory.
[ERROR] InnoDB: Could not find a valid tablespace file for ``test`.`test``. Please refer to https://mariadb.com/kb/en/innodb-data-dictionary-troubleshooting/ for how to resolve the issue.
[Warning] InnoDB: Ignoring tablespace for `test`.`test` because it could not be opened.
```

I already tried giving mysql user all file permissions to /home and /home/admin (using setfacl).

```
getfacl /home
# file: home
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rwx
user:mysql:rwx
group::r-x
mask::rwx
other::r-x

getfacl /home/admin
#file: home/admin
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rwx
user:mysql:rwx
user:admin:rwx
group::r-x
group:admin:r-x
mask::rwx
other::r-x
```

There is also no apparmor rule for mysql/mariadb:

```
apparmor module is loaded.
15 profiles are loaded.
14 profiles are in enforce mode.
   /usr/bin/freshclam
   /usr/bin/man
   /usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action
   /usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-helper
   /usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script
   /usr/sbin/clamd
   /usr/sbin/tcpdump
   /{,usr/}sbin/dhclient
   docker-default
   lsb_release
   man_filter
   man_groff
   nvidia_modprobe
   nvidia_modprobe//kmod
1 profiles are in complain mode.
   /usr/sbin/named
3 processes have profiles defined.
0 processes are in enforce mode.
0 processes are in complain mode.
3 processes are unconfined but have a profile defined.
   /usr/bin/freshclam (571) 
   /usr/sbin/clamd (455) 
   /usr/sbin/named (495)
```

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It took me a while, but just after posting the question I solved it.

In `/var/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service` is a line

```
ProtectHome=true
```

Changed to `false` and it works now.

Edit: in newer ubuntu versions the file is located here `/usr/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service`

Comment: Please have a look at [Can I answer my own question?](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) and come back two days later and check as answered if you have more than 15 reputation.